# accumulated calculation in sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, t-sql

I want to do this query on sql server

I can do this with loop but would like to know if there is any easier way that has better performance

I have table for referrals , 
scenario 1 : if A has 5 points and refer B that has 7 then the query should show 12 pts for A (A points + B points)
scenario 2 : if A has 5 and refer to B that has 7 and A refer to C that has 3 points and B refer to D that has 4 pts and so on..
in this case A takes all points of people A + B + C + D

my table look like this

**Refs**

sID bigint

sName varchar(50)

sPoints int

sRefID bigint

[image: data]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do this using recursive SQL. Try this:

```
With CTETable (sID, sRefID, sName, sPoints)
AS
(
SELECT Refs.sID, Refs.sRefID, Refs.sName, Refs.sPoints FROM Refs 
UNION ALL
SELECT Refs.sID, Refs.sRefID, CTETable.sName, Refs.sPoints 
FROM Refs INNER JOIN CTETable ON CTETable.sID = Refs.sRefID
)
Select sName, Sum(sPoints)
From CTETable
Group By CTETable.sName
```

This will yeild:

```
sName   TotalPoints
A   360
B   210
C   130
D   80
E   90
F   90
G   60
H   40
I   20
J   50
```

Comment: Thanks but i can not use left outer join in this query to join other table. any work around?

Comment: @asmgx do you want to use `left outer join` in this query why?

Comment: in the actual scenario  the Points will be calculated from another table and that if it is empty for A this means that A has 0 points, to get the sum(points) for someone with no points this requires left join

Comment: @asmgx, you should have provided all the tables for the actual scenario. No one can provide an answer without knowing all tables that are involved. Nevertheless, it should be possible to combine with a left outer join - take care to modify the recursive sql accordingly.

Comment: i did that but getting this error Msg 462, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
Outer join is not allowed in the recursive part of a recursive common table expression 'CTETable'.

Comment: You are right - an Outer Join is not allowed when using a CTE in a recursive SQL statement. You will likely need to re-think your DB structure. Maybe you can try this using a view instead of joining tables. But I fear the result may be the same.